# Pandas Dataframe: How to perform operation on 2 columns from different direction

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm struggling with the following problem and I can't find any elegant solution except iterating in a loop though every element of a series.

I need to perform a product then a sum on each element of a dataframa as follow

### input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1,6,1), 'b':range(10,60,10)})
```

### Intermediate output:

```
df=
   a   b
0  1  10
1  2  20
2  3  30
3  4  40
4  5  50
```

Now I want to perform the following operation (basically start from both ends, but not exactly as reversing the order of one column):

```
df['c'][0] = df['a'][0] * df['b'][4]
df['c'][1] = df['a'][0] * df['b'][3] + df['a'][1] * df['b'][4]
df['c'][2] = df['a'][0] * df['b'][2] + df['a'][1] * df['b'][3] + df['a'][2] * df['b'][4]
...
df['c'][4] = df['a'][0] * df['b'][0] + df['a'][1] * df['b'][1] + ... + df['a'][4] * df['b'][4]
```

### Final output:

```
df=
   a   b   c
0  1  10   50
1  2  20   40+ 100 =140
2  3  30   30 + 80 + 150 = 260
3  4  40   20 + 60 + 120 + 200 = 400
4  5  50   10 + 40 + 90 + 160 + 250 = 550
```

Of course the data here are simplified, there will be around 1000 rows, but the principle is the same.

I'm wondering if there is a way to find an elegant/efficient solution with apply() and cumsum().

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this calculation is called `convolve`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1,6,1), 'b':range(10,60,10)})
np.convolve(df["a"].values, df["b"].values[::-1])[:5]
```

output:

```
array([ 50, 140, 260, 400, 550])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That works perfectly. I'm wondering the convolve calculation can be accelerated. I need to dig a bit more this method.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following lines will do, but note that you have to construct rather large matrix for a large dataframe:

```
>>> import scipy.linalg
>>> x = np.zeros(len(df['b']))
>>> x[0] = list(df['b'])[-1]
>>> mult = scipy.linalg.toeplitz(x, df['b'][::-1])
>>> np.dot(df['a'], mult)
0     50
1    140
2    260
3    400
4    550
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did roughly the same though not as concise as your solution, but I was wondering there is a way to avoid creating a (large) matrix. (I updated my question to reflect this)